# No login prompt on console Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (running on qemu Synology)

Tags: login, virtualization, qemu, prompt

With one of the last Ubuntu updates I can't login on console anymore, because I'm getting no login prompt.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a Synology Virtual Machine and try to connect to the console via the web interface. I only see some kernel messages.

I tried to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 / Ctrl+F1, but no success. I guess the web interface doesn't send these special key combination correctly.

Any ideas?

These are the last kernel messages. I would expect some logging about services and finally the login prompt, but nothing happens after the blacklist message.

```
[    0.462290] ACPI: \_SB_.LNKD: Enabled at IRQ 11
[    0.508055] pci 0000:00:01.2: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x640 took 94656 usecs
[    0.508735] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.509400] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.509890] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x3990bc5adef, max_idle_ns: 881590438240 ns
[    0.509941] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.511529] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.527548] Key type blacklist registered
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `nomodeset` to the grub default command line.

`cat /etc/default/grub|grep nomodeset`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet text nomodeset"
```

Executed `update-grub` afterwards and rebooted.

Comment: For me, with Debian trixie, it worked only after adding `text` and `nomodeset`.